# How to use tabPanel as input in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to perform an action if the user clicks into a particular `tabPanel`?

For instance, if the user clicks into `tabPanel("A", ...)` then display a popup saying `You are viewing tab "A"`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`tabsetPanel()` will return the value assigned to the active `tabPanel()`. If you just want to update another output you could do something like this:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)    

shinyUI(basicPage( 

  textOutput("text"),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("Tab A", value = "A", "This is Tab A content"),
          tabPanel("Tab B", value = "B", "Here's some content for tab B.")
  )

))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$text <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab \"", input$tabs, "\"")})

})
```

but something more complicated like creating a popup would probably require making an observer and some additional custom coding...

Comment: example doesn't work... values is not defined! 
Did u mean input$tabs instead of values$tabValue?

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from a previous version of my answer. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer. It helps me fixed issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using shiny dashboard, `input$tabBox_id` will locate the active tab name. Refer to here: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#tabbox